# Можно ли оставить в релизной версии приложения setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)

Tags: android, отладка, webview

У меня идет настройка веб вью, которая стала для меня настоящим адом, поскольку на разных устройствах WebView ведет себя некорректно. После добавления этой строки в настройки `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)` - все начало отрабатывать корректно. Можно ли оставить это в релизной версии приложения? Не будет ли потом проблем с заливом прилки.

Comment: Лучше не надо :) Звучит стремно, может и google play пропустит приложение, но выкатывать такое в прод я бы не советовал. Все дебаг-флаги в релизном приложении должны быть выключены, на то они и дебажные.

Comment: @Vadik Так это дебаг js, html, css. К андроиду это никакого отношения не имеет

Comment: WebView запускается не в вакууме, а внутри вашего приложения. Вот [тут](https://ashishb.net/security/android-security-dont-leave-webview-debugging-enabled-in-production/) сказано, что если этот флаг включен, то можно получить доступ к приватной директории вашего приложения.